# ¿Se puede validar que una cadena contenga algo igual ignorando mayúsculas y minúsculas?

Tags: java, android-studio, poo, condiciones

Se tiene una cadena a la cual se necesita validar que contenga una palabra ignorando mayúsculas y minúsculas. Hasta el momento solo sé que se puede validar una por una.

Validando que contenga la palabra:

```
    var cadena = "Hola mundo";
    
    if (cadena.contains("Hola")) {
        System.out.println("Si la contiene");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No la contiene");
    }
```

Validando que sea igual ignorando mayúsculas y minúsculas:

```
    var cadena = "Hola Mundo";
    
    if (cadena.equalsIgnoreCase("hola mundo")) {
        System.out.println("Si es igual");
    } else {
        System.out.println("No es igual");
    }
```

Lo que se está buscando es que se puedan unir esas dos validaciones en una sola.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prueba poniendo el método `toLowerCase()`, que convierte el texto a minusculas, y luego comprobar si contiene el texto:

```
var cadena = "Hola Mundo";
String texto = cadena.toLowerCase();

if(texto.contains("hola mundo")) {
    System.out.println("Si es igual");
} else {
    System.out.println("No es igual");
}
```

Comment: O también con `toUpperCase()`, que convierte el texto a mayúsculas; luego `if(texto.contains("HOLA MUNDO")){`(...)`}`.

Answer (score 1):

Una manera seria convertir tanto la fuente, como el valor buscado en minúsculas o mayúsculas, de esa manera no importa como coloques ambos datos, si las frases son iguales obtendrás la validación correcta

**toLoweCase()** convierte una cadena en minuscula

**toUpperCase()** convierte una cadena en mayuscula

```
 var cadena = "Hola Mundo"; 
 if (cadena.toLowerCase().contains("hola Mundo".toLowerCase())) {
            System.out.println("Si es igual");
```

Answer (score 1):

Teniendo en cuenta todas sus opciones, hice una versión en la que se puede ver un poco mas resumido:

```
    var cadena = "Hola Mundo";
    
    if (cadena.toLowerCase().contains("hola mundo")) {
        System.out.println("Si es igual");
    }
```